# Rust deterministic, uniform distribution

Tags: rust, random, statistics

I am looking at the rand crate and I am not sure how to sample from a distribution such that the resulting samples are uniform and deterministic.

Deterministic means that you get the same numbers on 2 distinct program invocations.

The main issue I am facing is that rand by default is not deterministic. Id does have rand_pcg for determinism, but then I don;t know how to make the distribution uniform.

Comment: The keyword you want to search for is **reproducibility** rather than *deterministic*. You get reproducibility by choosing a PRNG that allows you to seed it and does not systematically reseed from entropy sources.  See https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/rngs/index.html. I'm not a rust programmer (yet), so I'm giving you this pointer rather than attempting to code it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rand` crate supports everything you are asking for.

### Uniformity

The `gen*` functions on the [`Rng` trait](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/trait.Rng.html) do this. Under the hood, they actually defer to the [`Standard` distribution](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/distributions/struct.Standard.html), which is simply uniform distribution for most common types.

If you wish to provide a custom distribution, simply use `Rng::sample*` functions and provide a distribution of your choice.

### Determinism

You are looking for [`SeedableRng`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/trait.SeedableRng.html). As the name implies, rngs that implement this trait should be able to accept a seed on initialisation. Note that determinism is not actually guaranteed by this trait (it depends on the implementation of the specific rng), although in practice seedable rngs are usually deterministic. One such rng provided is [`StdRng`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/rngs/struct.StdRng.html), but you can also implement your own rng if you so desire.

Note that there is a difference between "deterministic" and "reproducible", as outlined in `StdRng`'s documentation:

> The algorithm is deterministic but should not be considered reproducible due to dependence on configuration and possible replacement in future library versions. For a secure reproducible generator, we recommend use of the rand_chacha crate directly.

### Example

```rust
use rand::{rngs::StdRng, Rng, SeedableRng};

fn main() {
    let mut rng = StdRng::seed_from_u64(69420);
    let x: i32 = rng.gen(); // uniform distribution

    // this value could be different on you machine (not necessarily reproducible)
    // and it's not guaranteed to be the same across rust&rand versions
    // but it should be consistent across runs (deterministic)
    assert_eq!(x, -817183091);
}
```